# Jasmine get current spec test result

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, jasmine2.0

In jasmine v2.1.1, I used to:

`var passed = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results().passed();`

But after updating to Jasmine v2.5.2, I cannot do it anymore... Looks like `currentSpec` has been discontinued. How do I know if a test passed or not without doing a custom reporter?

Comment: Need more info. How are you running the tests?